# How can I use Linq to get correctly group these results?

Tags: linq

I have the following data set:

```
Year   Category  Score
2011   A         83
2012   A         86
2013   A         62
2011   B         89
2012   B         86
2013   B         67
2011   C         85
2012   C         73
2013   C         79
2011   D         95
2012   D         78
2013   D         67
```

I want to transform to the following structure.

```
categories: [2011, 2012, 2013], 
series: [
   { data: [83, 86, 62], name: 'A' }, 
   { data: [85, 73, 79], name: 'B' }, 
   { data: [83, 86, 62], name: 'C' }, 
   { data: [95, 78, 67], name: 'D' }]
```

I'd like the code to be tolerant of 'missing' data in the source data set. It's a safe assumption that at least 1 of each year and category is represented in the source data.

Example of 'sketchy' data

```
Year   Category  Score
2011   A         83
// 2012 A is missing
2013   A         62
// 2011 B is missing    
2012   B         86
2013   B         67
2011   C         85
// 2012 C is missing    
2013   C         79
2011   D         95
2012   D         78
2013   D         67
```

Should yield this:

```
categories: [2011, 2012, 2013], 
series: [
   { data: [83,  0, 62], name: 'A' }, 
   { data: [ 0, 73, 79], name: 'B' }, 
   { data: [83,  0, 62], name: 'C' }, 
   { data: [95, 78, 67], name: 'D' }]
```

Comment: this is my current working code. http://pastebin.com/F1XVmhPP.
I'm concerned about clarity, and number of steps to get to the answer.

Comment: Its useful if you post your code into the question, most people dont like following third party links to peoples stuff. If your code is complex reduce it to the simplest possible to demonstrate your issue. In this case a single linq statement demonstrating what you have tried would be ideal.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions @LukeMcGregor. I'll add it to the question body next time. I don't know if it can be done with a single expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created the following LINQPad code from pastebin code - see notes that follow implementation:

```
void Main()
{
    var scores = new [] {
        new CScore { Year = 2011, Category = 'A', Score = 83 },
        // 2012 A is missing
        new CScore { Year = 2013, Category = 'A', Score = 62 },
        // 2011 B is missing   
        new CScore { Year = 2012, Category = 'B', Score = 86 },
        new CScore { Year = 2013, Category = 'B', Score = 67 },
        new CScore { Year = 2011, Category = 'C', Score = 85 },
        // 2012 C is missing 
        new CScore { Year = 2013, Category = 'C', Score = 79 },
        new CScore { Year = 2011, Category = 'D', Score = 95 },
        new CScore { Year = 2012, Category = 'D', Score = 78 },
        new CScore { Year = 2013, Category = 'D', Score = 67 },
    };

    int[] years = scores.Select(i => i.Year).Distinct()
        .OrderBy(i=>i).ToArray();
    char[] categories = scores.Select(i => i.Category).Distinct()
        .OrderBy(i=>i).ToArray();

    var series =
        from year in years
        from cat in categories
        join score in scores
        on new { Year = year, Category = cat }
        equals new { score.Year, score.Category } into scoreGroup
        select scoreGroup.SingleOrDefault() ??
            new CScore { Year = year, Category = cat } into scoreWithDefault
        group scoreWithDefault.Score by scoreWithDefault.Category into g
        select new Series { Name = g.Key.ToString(), Data = g.ToArray() };

    years.Dump(); // categories
    series.Dump(); // series
}

class CScore
{
    public char Category {get;set;}
    public int Year {get;set;}
    public int Score {get;set;}
}

class Series
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int[] Data {get;set;}
}
```

#### Comments

1. `CScore` - renamed to avoid naming error I encountered
2. Sorted distinct items to avoid potential ordering challenges depending on input data.
3. series query:

   1. The from clauses form a cross product of all category/year combinations.
   2. The `join..into` permits the default `CScore` generation for missing years
   3. I chose `SingleOrDefault` so that ***IF*** the input data had more than one matching CScore item on the join, the query would throw an `InvalidOperationException` indicating that something more ought to be done to deal with the redundancy. I find this preferable to a `FirstOrDefault` that wouldn't fail in this bad-data/strange-data case.
   4. Omitted `Score = 0` in the `CScore` initializer block since 0 is the default.
   5. `select..into` query continuation permitted the query to be fed into the `group..by` that groups the score by the category/name. I really appreciated the null coalesce operator here.
   6. `group..by..into g` -- the `Series` type is analogous to the `IGrouping<char,int>` that I would used if I had stopped with the group-by. Instead the final select projects that IGrouping type to the desired `Series` type.

I verified the answer in the LINQPad output - and discovered a couple of flaws in the 'should yield this' sample output data. Also, this code executes in about a millisecond on my machine, so unless we have lots more data than this to process, I wouldn't be tempted to improve it.

Despite there being more we could talk about - I'll leave it right there. Hopefully I didn't lose anybody.

Comment: Thanks @devgeezer!
I really appreciate the thorough explanation. I had not realized that my cross join could be expressed in the same expression. The "into scoreGroup" could be named more clearly because there's not a 'group' component to the result. I appreciate the improvement of SingleOrDefault as well.

Comment: That scoreGroup name was chosen because the compiler translates that "join .. into scoreGroup" into an GroupJoin call - maybe not the best motivation for a name. Regardless, glad to help and thanks for an interesting LINQ challenge.